# CrossWalk with ProGuard

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime, android-proguard, crosswalk

I am trying to enable ProGuard on a Cordova/CrossWalk application project.

The project is using a CrossWalk v13 jar rather thank compiling.

I have tried both of the following ProGaurd config options:

- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html
- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html

I keep getting an 'occasional' startup crash with the following:

Mostly on first launches.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: check the faq page -- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html  -- (How to use Crosswalk on a project using ProGuard)

Comment: I already tried that Tasos, as mentioned. I have tried both of the links above

Comment: sorry i thought you had different links in your Q.

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following to my crosswalk and have not been having issues.

```
# XWalk
-keep class org.xwalk.core.** { *; }
-keep class org.crosswalk.engine.** { *; }
-keep class org.chromium.** { *; }
-keepattributes **
-dontwarn android.view.**
-dontwarn android.media.**
-dontwarn org.chromium.**
```

I'm including crosswalk not as a jar but as a gradle dependency by first adding the repo in the repository block:

```
 maven { url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2' }
```

And then adding the dependency

```
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18.48.477.2'
```

Comment: In my case to avoid app crash at the start it is enough to use only `keep class org.xwalk.core.** { *; }` and `keep class org.xwalk.core.** { *; }`. I use code shrinking (minifyEnabled=true) and resource shrinking (shrinkResources=true).